# Cube Camera not working

Tags: three.js, camera

I'm new to javascript and three.js and am trying to make a "chrome material" for the frame of this stool I've loaded.  From what I've read I need a cube camera to create the illusion of a reflection.  After days of searching online I can't for the life of me figure out why I can't get it to work. It just renders the frame black(and the seat is black but that's a separate issue). Can anyone help with this?

```
//webGL

var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

camera.position.set(0, 16, 25);
camera.rotation.x += -0.32;

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

cubeCamera = new THREE.CubeCamera(1, 1000, 256); // parameters: near, far, resolution
cubeCamera.renderTarget.texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearMipMapLinearFilter; // mipmap filter
scene.add(cubeCamera);

///LOADERS
var loadTexture = new THREE.TextureLoader();
var loaderJs = new THREE.JSONLoader();


///TEXTURES
var skyTexture = loadTexture.load("textures/background.jpg");
var seatTexture = loadTexture.load("textures/Maharam_Mister_Notice_Diffuse.jpg");

///MATERIALS
var skyMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    side: THREE.DoubleSide,
    map: skyTexture
});
var frameMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
    //envMap: cubeCamera.renderTarget,
    color: 0xffffff
});
var seatMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
        map: seatTexture
});


///GEOMETRY and MESHES 
var frameGeo;

var skyGeo = new THREE.SphereGeometry(30, 30, 30);
var skySphere = new THREE.Mesh(skyGeo, skyMaterial);
scene.add(skySphere);

loaderJs.load("models/stoolFrame.js", function (){
    frameGeo = new THREE.Mesh(frameGeo, frameMaterial);
    frameGeo.scale.set(.5, .5, .5);
    barStool.add(frameGeo);
});

loaderJs.load("models/stoolSeat.js", function (seatGeo){
    seatGeo = new THREE.Mesh(seatGeo, seatMaterial);
    seatGeo.scale.set(.5, .5, .5);
    barStool.add(seatGeo);
});


var barStool = new THREE.Object3D();
scene.add(barStool);

    var render = function () {

        requestAnimationFrame(render);
        barStool.rotation.y += 0.01;

        frameGeo.visible = false;
        cubeCamera.position.copy(frameGeo.position);
        cubeCamera.updateCubeMap(renderer, scene);
        frameGeo.visible = true;


        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    };



render();
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to help you, because i see many errors in your scene.

if you add an object into object3d you don't have to add it into scene, when you add barStool you add also all child.

the call to render function after js load is not necessary, when you put the object into the scene it will be rendered automatically.

if you want to add a reflection with cubecamera you have to render it, in the render loop you have to insert the following line to hide the chrome object for update the world reflection map:

```
requestAnimationFrame(render);
barStool.rotation.y += 0.01;

frameGeo.visible=false;
cubeCamera.position.copy(frameGeo.position);
cubeCamera.updateCubeMap(renderer, scene);
frameGeo.visible = true;

renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

I suggest you to start with a simple scene, check if it's rendered correctly and then add new feature... one step for time...

Comment: Thankyou for your response!  Your comments on the cubeCamera make a lot of sense.  However I get an error "frameGeo is undefined." I've ran into similar issues working with this - I believe its because "frameGeo" is a variable nested in the loader function.  I may need to post another question regarding that issue If I'm unable to resolve it myself.

Comment: you have to declare `var frameGeo;` at the top of the script.

Comment: Again, thankyou for working through this with me.  I've implemented your suggestions (correctly I think) but am getting the following error:  WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: bindTexture: textures can not be used with multiple targets
localhost/:1 [.CommandBufferContext]RENDER WARNING: Render count or primcount is 0.

Comment: Finally got it to work! well - kinda.  I was able to use what you suggested for the update section of code on a new THREE.SphereGeometry.  However I'm still working through trying to get it to work on geometry thats loaded via JSONLoader